# How can i sort a string without using sort() method in java?

Tags: java, string, sorting

I want to sort a string "computer" -> "cemoprtu", but without using Arrays.sort(string).

Comment: Has any particular sorting algorithm been given to you to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to sort the characters, so I'd start with

```
String input = "computer";
char[] characters = input.toCharArray();
//now sort characters using some algorithm
String output = new String(sorted_characters); //sorted_characters might be characters after sorting, if you sort in place
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out different [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) and implement a couple, try bubble then quick sort.

Comment: Every time I see bubble sort I die a little on the inside. (Just my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

```
package practice;


class Practice
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
   String s = "bcfaed";
   char a[]=s.toCharArray();
   char b[]=new char[a.length];
   int count=0;
   for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
   {
       count=0;
       for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
       {
       if(a[i]<a[j])
       {
       count++;
       }
       }
       b[count]=a[i];
   }
   for(char x:b)
   {
       System.out.println(x);
   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
class Abc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "welcome";
        char temp = 0;

        char arr[] = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[j] > arr[i]) {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Abc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "welcome";
        char temp = 0;

        char arr[] = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[j] > arr[i]) {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Java program to sort 
// a string of characters 
public class SortString{ 
    static final int MAX_CHAR = 26; 
  
    // function to print string in sorted order 
    static void sortString(String str) { 
  
        // Hash array to keep count of characters. 
        int letters[] = new int[MAX_CHAR]; 
  
        // Traverse string and increment 
        // count of characters 
        for (char x : str.toCharArray()) { 
  
            // 'a'-'a' will be 0, 'b'-'a' will be 1, 
            // so for location of character in count 
            // array we will do str[i]-'a'. 
            letters[x - 'a']++; 
        } 
  
        // Traverse the hash array and print 
        // characters 
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < letters[i]; j++) { 
                System.out.print((char) (i + 'a')); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
  
    // Driver program to test above function 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        sortString("eeffjaaannnfffnn"); 
    } 
}
```